Android Studio and Pycharm crashes linux os
this photo
Sorry for bad photo. I captured in hurry.
Thing is these programs worked at windows with no problem, but i installed ubuntu, it crashes system and gives this text while restart.
I wanted to open android studio and pycharm.

"gives this text..." what text?

You might want to run a mem-check.
